# How to fix the "Setting locale failed" error while installing vim?

Tags: installation, software-center, vim

When installing `vim` through Software Center , I get this error

```
installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-10ubuntu4) ...
/etc/environment: line 1: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-10ubuntu4) ...
/etc/environment: line 1: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: Try sudo dpkg-reconfigure locale

Comment: it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to generate your local files.  This is done use the `locale-gen` command.  The argument needed is the language and charset you want to set the system to.

For example, if I want my system to use English (US) with UTF-8, I would run the following command.

`locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`

It looks like you are from India and might want to run something like this.

`locale-gen en_IN.ISO8859-1`

Comment: sir i tried your commands and generated all the locale files but still its showing the same error, i am new to linux please help me with this.

Comment: not working....

Comment: I think reboot might be needed..

Answer (score 0):

first:

```
sudo apt-get purge locales
```

then:

```
sudo aptitude install locales
```

and the famous:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

This rids the system of locales, then re-installs locales and downgrades libc6 from 2.19 to 2.13 which is the issue quite likely. Then configures locales again.

Comment: sounds promising